# chart.js does not render when submitting data to create a bar graph

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js, jinja2

chart.js does not render when submitting data to create a bar graph.
I've previously tried to test bar graph generation using chart.js version 2.9.4 (if using other versions the graphs won't show. I don't understand why either)
which can bring information from phpmyadmin to display normally But when I actually use it in my project when sending data to dashboard.html Graphs will not display data. But when no data is sent, the graph will show as an empty graph as in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jSdf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrOwk.png)

I would like to know how to make the graph display the data.

This is the app.py file.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # ===============================aqi data===============================
    cur.execute(f'SELECT avg, time FROM aqi ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 24')
    result = cur.fetchall()
    avg = [r[0] for r in result[::-1]]
    date = [r[1].strftime('%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S') for r in result[::-1]]
    return render_template('dashboard.html', avg_data=avg, date_data=date)
```

and this is dashboard.html

```
\<!DOCTYPE html\>
\<html lang="en"\>

\<head\>
\<meta charset="UTF-8"\>
\<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"\>
\<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"\>
\<title\>Dashboard\</title\>
\<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous"\>
\<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/dashboard_style.css"\>
\<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"\>
\<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"\>
\<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"\>\</script\>
\<script\>
function updateTime() {
var currentTime = new Date();
var dateOptions = { day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' };
var timeOptions = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' };
var date = currentTime.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', dateOptions);
var time = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', timeOptions);
document.getElementById('datetime').innerHTML = date + ' ' + time;
}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
\</script\>
\</head\>

\<body onload="updateTime()"\>
\<div class="box-content" style="height: 265px;"\>
\<canvas id="myChart" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"\>\</canvas\>
\</div\>

    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 500);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)'); // red at the top
        gradient.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(255, 162, 0, 0.3)'); // red at the top
        gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(255, 255, 60, 0.3)'); // red at the top
        gradient.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(132, 255, 0, 0.3)'); // red at the top
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.3)'); // blue at the bottom
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [{% for dt in date_data %} '{{ dt }}',{% endfor %}],
        // labels: [{% for dt in date_data %} '{{ dt }}',{% endfor %}],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Average/Hour : ',
            data: [{% for dt in avg_data %} {{ dt }}, {% endfor %}],
            type: 'line',
                borderColor: 'rgba(130, 130, 130, 1)',
                    fill: false,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                            pointRadius: 8,
                                tension: 0.3,
                                    backgroundColor: gradient,
                                        pointBackgroundColor: [{% for dt in avg_data %}
        {% if dt >= 0 and dt <= 25 %}
        'rgba(0, 204, 255, 1)',
            {% elif dt > 25 and dt <= 50 %}
        'rgba(132, 255, 0, 1)',
            {% elif dt > 50 and dt <= 100 %}
        'rgba(255, 255, 60, 1)',
            {% elif dt > 100 and dt <= 200 %}
        'rgba(255, 162, 0, 1)',
            {% else %}
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}],
    
                            }, {
            label: 'Average/Hour : ',
                data: [{% for dt in avg_data %} { { dt } }, {% endfor %}],
        backgroundColor: [{% for dt in avg_data %}
        {% if dt >= 0 and dt <= 25 %}
        'rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.3)',
            {% elif dt > 25 and dt <= 50 %}
        'rgba(132, 255, 0, 0.3)',
            {% elif dt > 50 and dt <= 100 %}
        'rgba(255, 255, 60, 0.3)',
            {% elif dt > 100 and dt <= 200 %}
        'rgba(255, 162, 0, 0.3)',
            {% else %}
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)',
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}],
    
        borderColor: [{% for dt in avg_data %}
        {% if dt >= 0 and dt <= 25 %}
        'rgba(0, 204, 255, 1)',
            {% elif dt > 25 and dt <= 50 %}
        'rgba(132, 255, 0, 1)',
            {% elif dt > 50 and dt <= 100 %}
        'rgba(255, 255, 60, 1)',
            {% elif dt > 100 and dt <= 200 %}
        'rgba(255, 162, 0, 1)',
            {% else %}
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}],
        borderWidth: 1
                        }],
                    },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 6
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: { display: false },
            title: {
                display: true,
                    text: "Air Quality Index (AQI)"
            },
            responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                }
            });
    </script>
        <!-- <script>
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 10000);
        </script> -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
\</body\>
\</html\>
```

I would like to know how to make the graph display the data.

Comment: Having a look to your code, I have the feeling the "labels" and "data" options sounds to be built wrongly. Can you show the data.datasets.data array value? I think it could be better to create an array outside of chart config and scan the values and adding them by "push" method.

Comment: This is the value in the array.
avg :  [81, 95, 90, 116, 130, 149]

date :  ['Apr 05, 2023 15:28:42', 'Apr 05, 2023 15:28:52', 'Apr 05, 2023 15:29:02', 'Apr 05, 2023 15:29:12', 'Apr 05, 2023 15:29:22', 'Apr 05, 2023 15:29:32']